# jquery multiple assigning class name for mouseover or hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, jquery-hover

I am trying to assign a multiple `classnames` to `hover()` ,here is my jquery function

```
$(".bigbox").hover(function(){

alert('divs selected')
});
```

now i wanted to add same function for one div

```
$(".smallbox").hover(function(){

alert('divs selected');
});
```

i want to try something like this

```
if($(".bigbox") || $(".smallbox"))
{ alert('divs selected'); }
```

how to achieve in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may write

```
$(".bigbox, .smallbox").hover(function(){
  alert('divs selected')
});
```

or, if you need to manage all `div` elements whose classes end with "box" you might also write

```
$("div[class $= 'box']").hover(function(){
  alert('divs selected')
});
```

(this could be an useful alternative if you plan to introduce and manage other box elements, like `.mediumbox` or `.hugebox`)